# How to color SVG with CSS without specifying all basic shapes?

Tags: css, svg, sass

Using `CSS` I am able to color `SVG` graphics as follows:

```
svg polygon, svg line, svg polyline, svg path, svg mesh, svg rect, svg circle, svg ellipse {
        fill: Gray;
}
```

Is there a shorter way of doing this avoiding specifying all SVG basic shapes? Any solution with `SASS`?

Comment: svg { fill: gray } should do if you don't specify any fill in the markup as it will cascade into all the children.

Comment: @RobertLongson That technique unfortunately doesn't work. Maybe because the SVG is embedded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a sass solution, you could use a mixin:

```
@mixin style-svg {
    svg {
        polygon,
        line,
        polyline,
        path,
        mesh,
        rect,
        circle,
        ellipse {
            @content;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like

```
@include style-svg {
    fill: gray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add class names to svg objects like path, g, text and create css styles with some, not all svg values in the class name. The rest you can add to style for that object.

```
.line {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  fill: none;
}

<path d="m490,130 L473,110" class="line" style="marker-end: url(#markerArrow);"></path>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: That means editing the SVG files with sees more cumbersome than simply listing all the SVG shapes.

Comment: I see you're new at this.

I explained a technique I use with svg. You might have multiple lines, shapes in multiple graphics you want to style and using class names can help you do that. It works with sass, so you can use the tags for your other color values. You might want to create classes based on values for success, for danger, it just allows you an easy way to customize your look without changing the svg graphic in multiple places.